# Why do the monsters have super power, scale buildings and have a large jaw?

Tags: i-am-legend

Why do the monsters in *I Am Legend* have super powers? When they hit the car with their heads they act like it was nothing. Or when the "alpha monster" hit the glass that Robert is inside, can he actuality break the glass like that?

How do they scale buildings so easily? What do they have that made this possible in such an easy way?

Why do they have that large jaw? My guess is because they use the mouth a lot, to scream, to bite, etc. But is that alone sufficient to explain this?

Comment: Well, it's simply the nature of that virus. What other explanation do you actually expect?

Comment: To be honestly, i was expecting more explanation about the monsters in the movie. But you answer is satisfactory.

Comment: The monster in that movie was indeed weak and ineffective, having been caught in his own trap. If 99% of the world has been infected and changed, isn't the monster the one who kills the masses?

Comment: @cgc your confused with the original.

Comment: @cde no I'm not, but understand why you think so

Comment: Intelligence is knowing Frankenstein isn't the monster. Wisdom is knowing Frankenstein is the monster.

Comment: @theguest, okay, i will read the original novel, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I honestly think that in the movie, they were just doing their best to make the monsters as menacing as possible.

They are very different from the monsters in the book, which resemble vampires more than zombies like in the movie. In the book, there were even several of the creatures that could think and speak, which made them all the more terrifying.

By making them nearly invincible in the movie, and giving them large mouths so they could scream, i think they were trying to recover for the fact that the monsters didn't have the same capabilities as in the book.

That's just my guess though. I love this movie, but as in most cases, i think the book is much better and can't understand why they changed it so much.